# Apache segfault by cakePHP website

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, segmentation-fault

Without any -apparent- reasons, one of my cakePHP websites (v1.3.11) has stopped working (showing a "no data received" page in chrome - error 324) but the other is still fine -for the moment at least-.

/var/log/apache2/error.log shows a `[notice] child pid 8502 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)`

and /var/log/messages shows `kernel: [15482058.932226] apache2[8502]: segfault at 7fff7f14fb58 ip 7f1b9d886e55 sp 7fff7f14fb60 error 6 in libphp5.so[7f1b9d576000+588000]`

Here's my php -v

```
PHP 5.2.6-1+lenny13 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.6.2 (cli) (built: Jul  1 2011 16:01:01)
Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2008 Zend Technologies
```

I absolutely have no idea on what heppened, so any idea is welcome.

**EDIT:**

It looks like the `render()` function in the /cake/libs/controller/controller.php is doing an infinite loop. Any ideas why this is happening? (it's happening on all the pages of the website and no code has changed lately...)

Comment: Have you changed/updated your PHP version on the server recently? Also worth noting that every time I have ever had a segfault in PHP it because of a recursive function being called too many times and running out of memory. The Zend engine handles this incorrectly and causes a segfault. I have yet to get to the bottom of the reason why.

Comment: Already restarted apache2, no success.

Comment: @Dave: I don't think so, although the php -v above seems to say so. How could I downgrade it then? I think it's more likely to be a loop as you said.

Comment: @Dave: look at the edit section.

Comment: @Nicholas I am not that good with the inner workings of cake, I may have to bow out at this point, although it sounds like you're getting closer to an answer... if I can come up with anything I'll let you know.

Comment: @Dave: cheers. That's definitively the `render()` function which is infinitively looping, but I don't understand why. I'm just calling it by doing `$this->render('whatever_view');`. And the strange part is I'm not even sure it is cake's fault as I'm making the same calls on the other cakePHP site on the same server using the same cakePHP framework version =/

Comment: Without basically reverse engineering all of your code, and cake, it's going to be very hard to work out what is going on. The only thing I can think of if you haven't changed the code recently is that maybe some config file got accidentally deleted, and it's now using some default value which is causing the problem? It could be a lot of work to even find that though...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3067/discussion-between-nicolas-and-daverandom)

Comment: Maybe [this](http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Cake-core-code-infinite-loop-recursive-rendering-issue-td1289262.html) will push you in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downgraded my framework to what it was before thanks to a backup of those files I've done just before the updated and everything's fine now again.

Maybe something was wrong during the upload or something is not compatible with the latest version of the framework. I'll do some tests later about it and I'll comment on this "solution".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with cakephp 2.2.1.
I've resolved the issue by adding flush() in App.php's load function.

```
public static function load($className) {
    if (!isset(self::$_classMap[$className])) {
        return false;
    }
    flush();
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

on core.php

Configure::write('debug',0);

Comment: Amazing how something like this solved the problem, I was desperate!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this might be regression in the last security update of Debian. I get very similar errors as you have, but we are not running cake. If we can confirm this, we should file a bug at Debian.

/var/log/messages`[39144630.700032] apache2[13693]: segfault at 7fffff7fdfb8 ip 7f5195606a6a sp 7fffff7fdf50 error 6 in libphp5.so[7f519535c000+588000]`

/var/log/apache2/error.log`[error] child died with signal 11`

$ php -v

```
PHP 5.2.6-1+lenny13 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.6.2 (cli) (built: Jul  1 2011 16:01:01) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2008 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI I had the same problem today. Turning off debug kit solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

I suddenly got this problem after I added post editing to the blog tutorial on a local virtual host.
For me, this problem went away when I went back through my files and found a syntax mistake. Once I fixed the syntax, it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, turning off DebugKit solved this problem for me in CakePHP 2.3.5. Except for adding DebugKit, the CakePHP installation is completely fresh. I got the same error 324 in Chrome as mentioned in the original post.